# why the shapes become hidden when I add the codes for drawing triangles

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl

I write this code for drawing X axis :

```
   glPushMatrix();
   glColor3f(0.5f, 0, 0);
   glVertex3f(-size, 0, 0);
   glVertex3f( size, 0, 0);
   glPopMatrix();
```

but when I add this part of code to draw the arrows; all the other shape such as shperes become hidden:

```
 glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);     // Drawing Using Triangles
 glVertex3f( 10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);        // Top
 glVertex3f(9.0f, 0.25f, 0.0f);     // Bottom Left
 glVertex3f(9.0f,-0.25f, 0.0f);     // Bottom Right
 glEnd();
```

what is my wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem in this code

```
 glPushMatrix();
 glColor3f(0.5f, 0, 0);
 glVertex3f(-size, 0, 0);
 glVertex3f( size, 0, 0);
 glPopMatrix();
```

glVertex can be called only between glBegin and glEnd. But glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix are not allowed to be called between glBegin and glEnd. The way you wrote them they don't have any effect anyway, because there's no actual matrix manipulation happening.

On the other hand the Z coordinates for all your primitives is identical. So it's quite understandable that things will overdraw each other. I also bet you didn't enable depth testing at all, so it wouldn't matter anyway, because without depth testing things will overdraw other things regardless of depth.

Comment: ok! but in this way I can just draw x axis and others are hidden too;

Comment: @GolnazSaraji: Well, you probably have to select a depth buffer and enable depth testing. You must put your transformations differently, etc., etc. Given the little code you presented I can barely help you out with that. I'd have to see your full display function to be make substancial suggestions.